# React Form validation "Required" is not working in react js

Tags: reactjs

My React form validation is not working. I want to validate my login form. I tried many ways but it's not working. I find many ways in google but it's all confusing and not working. can someone help me out of this?

```
import { required, email } from 'react-admin';

export function Login(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <FormContainer>
        <Input
          type='text'
          className='form-control'
          placeholder='User name'
          name='username'
          onChange={handleChange}
          validate={[required(), email()]}
        />
        <Input
          type='password'
          className='form-control'
          placeholder='Password'
          name='password'
          onChange={handleChange}
          validate={[required()]}
        />
      </FormContainer>

      <SubmitButton type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Signin
      </SubmitButton>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `TextInput` instead of `input` to validate via react-admin. see this reference in their docs https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Edit, SimpleForm, ReferenceInput, SelectInput, TextInput, required } from 'react-admin';

export const PostEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit title={<PostTitle />} {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput disabled source="id" />
            <ReferenceInput label="User" source="userId" reference="users" validate={[required()]}>
                <SelectInput optionText="name" />
            </ReferenceInput>
            <TextInput source="title" label="Post title" validate={[required()]} />
            <TextInput multiline source="body" initialValue="Lorem Ipsum" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```